# How to filter in mysql date, time

Tags: php, mysql

In my database are date and time fields are separated rows, how do I filter like DateTime?

```
SELECT    
    ac_head_type, 
    ac_head_id,  
    narration, 
    amount, 
    user_id, 
    tr_time, 
    trans_no
FROM         
    vouchers  
WHERE   
    vouchers.tr_date >= '$d_start' 
    AND vouchers.tr_date <= '$d_end' 
    AND TIME(tr_time) >= '$time_start' 
    AND TIME(tr_time) <= '$time_end';
```

[Datas screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcvMa.jpg)

[image: Php my admin screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TIMESTAMP` to filter the data with different date and  time columns

For Ex :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE TIMESTAMP(datecol, timecol) > '2018-01-01 12:00:00';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE TIMESTAMP(datecol, timecol) BETWEEN fromTimeStamp AND nowTimeStamp
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE TIMESTAMP(tr_date, tr_time) BETWEEN '2018-09-04 07:00:00' AND '2018-09-05 03:24:18'

working..... :)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a string and then use the normal where clause filters

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE CONCAT(tr_date, ' ', tr_time) > '2018-01-01 12:00:00';
```